# Angular jquery plugin - jQuery is not defined in plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angular, webpack

i try to import the jquery-knob plugin in my Angular project, so i installed jquery via npm – that works fine. Now i want to add the jquery-knob (also via npm) but i get this error, i think its in the

> jquery.knob.min.js

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.310.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:1:85)
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.310.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:1:95)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at webpackJsonp.310.module.exports (addScript.js:9)
    at Object.155 (jquery.knob.min.js?4d31:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap aa173b5…:52)
    at Object.351 (addScript.js:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap aa173b5…:52)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap aa173b5…:23)
    at scripts.bundle.js:1
```

in .angluar-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery-knob"
      ],
```

component:

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
import * as knobObj from 'jquery-knob';
```

How can I pass the JQuery Instance to the jquery-knob plugin?

Used Version:

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.1
node: 6.10.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 4.1.0
@angular/compiler: 4.1.0
@angular/core: 4.1.0
@angular/forms: 4.1.0
@angular/http: 4.1.0
@angular/platform-browser: 4.1.0
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.0
@angular/router: 4.1.0
@angular/cli: 1.0.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Now i found a solution, maybe it helps somebody :-), I put the knob in a own component and create a native Element, then pass the values between with `input()` and `output()`, see the code:

myknob.component

```
import {Component, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import "jquery-knob";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-myknob',
  templateUrl: './myknob.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myknob.component.css']
})
export class MyknobComponent implements OnInit {

  knobElement: any;

  @Input() sliderVal : number;
  @Output() sliderValChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor(private elementRef : ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.knobElement = $(this.elementRef.nativeElement);
    this.knobElement.knob({
        "bgColor": "#FFF",
        "fgColor": "#222222",
        "thickness" : .2,
      change : (value) => this.setVal(value)
    });
    this.knobElement.val(this.sliderVal).trigger('change');


  }

  setVal(val) {

    this.sliderVal = val;
    this.sliderValChange.emit(this.sliderVal);
  }

}
```

myknob template:

```
<input type="text"  [attr.value]="sliderVal">
```

the parent component template

```
<app-myknob class="myKnob" [sliderVal]="inputVal" (sliderValChange)="setSliderVal($event)"></app-myknob>
```

the parent component

```
setSliderVal(sliderVal: number) {
    console.log(sliderVal);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [angular2-knob](https://github.com/xzegga/angular2-knob) instead jquery plugin, this package has been re-written completely for angular 4 using d3.js V4